# On screen keyboard is hiding content

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have an autocomplete text box that when typed in will show results in a popup directly below itself.

But when the user is using a virtual keyboard as soon as the keyboard shows it will scroll the the bottom of the textbox, This hides the results from showing when they appear.

Is there a way for me to get around this?

The only way i can think of is to set the vertical offset of the popup on each keypress that will position it above the textbox instead of below. But this is not how i would like it to work, i would much prefer the results to push the keyboard down or to scroll up the page.

Comment: How did you manage to get it working? I've just posted a [question with a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638117/programmatically-scroll-controls-into-view-when-virtual-keyboard-opens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue, I found this helpful:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Keyboard-Events-Sample-866ba41c